# Kotlin DSL adding Kotlin SourceSets doesn't affect

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, source-sets

I am adding `Kotlin` `SourceSets` to my project but I am unable to see `Kotlin` source in the `Project layout`.

> What I have in build.gradle.kts

```
sourceSets {
    getByName("main").java.srcDirs("src/main/kotlin")
}
```

> What I see in the project path

[image]

And also when I run `./gradlew sourcesets` task I see 2 sources for the module.

[image]

I googled it but couldn't find useful info. How can I have **kotlin** instead of **java**? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, It is too simple to do so. Just delete **java** source and create a new directory called **kotlin** inside `main`. Everything will be done.